# What is the physics engine used by DeepMimic?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I found a [video for the paper *DeepMimic: Example-Guided Deep Reinforcement Learning of Physics-Based Character Skills*](https://youtu.be/vppFvq2quQ0)
 on YouTube.

I looked in the related paper, but could not find details of how to the environment was created, such as the physics engine it used. I would like to use it, or something similar.

Comment: Its better you analyse your question inline with community guidelines.

Comment: @neilslater Any idea what software stack was used besides physics engine?

Comment: @gfdsal No, but I didn't answer this question. Your comment could be directed to user12075 on the answer, or you could start a new question given that this one was asked and answered over 18 months ago (the two posters might not be available here today).

Comment: @NeilSlater yup, thats why I tagged you directly. I shall start a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bullet physics engine](https://pybullet.org/wordpress/)

Their [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.02717.pdf) says

```
Physics simulation is performed at 1.2kHz using the Bullet physics engine [Bullet 2015].
```